# how to bind a c function which populates a pointer in haskell

Tags: haskell, ffi

So I'm lurking around Haskell ffi trying to figure how to do stuff.
I've bound couple functions which take and return integer values.
Now I want to bind a function which takes a pointer to a buffer, which it populates.
But Haskell doesn't have variables - it seems I can define a constant of type CIntPtr which i can then cast to CCharPtr and use sizeOf to get the buffer size, but how would i access the value later in said buffer afterwards?

I'm struggling to find a minimal example of binding a function which takes a pointer where it writes some value and accessing that value from haskell code.

Could anyone help me by providing / pointing one?
In case a more specific question is required: lets assume I want to bind[pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) syscall, call it, and get the values from haskell code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions from the [`Foreign.Marshal.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html) module. Here's an example:

`hello.c`

```c
void do_something(int* values) {
    values[0] = 1;
    values[1] = 2;
    values[2] = 3;
}
```

`Lib.hs`

```hs
import Foreign.C
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

foreign import ccall "do_something"
    c_do_something :: Ptr CInt -> IO ()

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
    xs <- allocaArray 10 $ \ptr -> do
        c_do_something ptr
        peekArray 10 ptr
    print xs
```

Executing this prints the following:

```
[1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```